# Relay, webpack and babel doesn't work as described

Tags: javascript, gulp, webpack, babeljs, relay

In my project I use gulp to run task, with webpack to compile js modules, which uses babel loader to transform react and ES6. Now I want to add relay transformation. I went by this instructions: https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-babel-plugin.html#advanced-usage but they doesnt' seem right.

I had to do some little reverse engineering and i produced following gulp task:

```js
gulp.task('js', () => {
    // Compile babel (react)
    gulp.src(paths.js)
        .pipe(er(webpack({
            module: {
                plugins: [
                    new require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin')({
                        React: "React",
                        Relay: 'Relay'
                    })
                ],
                loaders: [
                    {
                        test: /\.jsx?$/,
                        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                        loader: 'babel',
                        query: {
                            presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'],
                            plugins: [require('babel-relay-plugin')(require(paths.db_schema).data)]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            output: {
                filename: paths.js_output
            }
        })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});
```

Now I get such error for every processed file:

```
ERROR in (filename)
Module build failed: TypeError: Falsy value found in plugins
    at d:\Node\organize.me\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:187:15
    at Array.map (native)
    at Function.normalisePlugins (d:\Node\organize.me\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:182:20)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (d:\Node\organize.me\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:298:36)
    at OptionManager.init (d:\Node\organize.me\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:481:10)
    at File.initOptions (d:\Node\organize.me\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:211:75)
    at new File (d:\Node\organize.me\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:129:22)
    at Pipeline.transform (d:\Node\organize.me\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:48:16)
    at transpile (d:\Node\organize.me\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:14:22)
    at Object.module.exports (d:\Node\organize.me\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:88:12)
 @ multi main
```

I did wome more of reverse engineering and i found out that array in plugins is just `[ null ]` when i replace that line with

```
plugins: [new (require('babel-relay-plugin')(require(paths.db_schema).data))()]
```

I get error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Plugin' of undefined
```

So how can i make gulp, webpack, babel and relay work together?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Try to use `babel-relay-plugin-loader` but be aware of versions of the loader plugin and the `babel-relay-plugin`

Comment: thx. I had to use the .babelrc to load the plugin instead of mentioning it in webpack.